# Debugging in Visual Studio 2013 express

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug a fairly complex program with VS2013 express for Desktop. I would like it to pause at every line of code. While I could place a breakpoint on every line of code, that is tedious and inefficient. Is there a way to debug the application in steps to halp me locate the problem? I'm trying to debug a 1000 line OpenCV program with nearly no whitespace, that I wrote in one sitting without debugging a single time!

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was looking for! ;). Thanks! Now, I'll be able to find the error. Apparently, it seems as though findContours is triggering a breakpoint and causing a corrupt heap! If anyone knows what to do, it would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a breakpoint at the first line of code, run until the breakpoint is hit, and then single-step through each line with either <kbd>F10</kbd> (Step Over) or <kbd>F11</kbd> (Step Into).

It's usually more useful to narrow down the code to a specific area by setting several breakpoints further apart, and then examining the state of variables at each breakpoint (using watchpoints makes that easier) to try and isolate the problem. Once you're able to narrow the scope to a specific function or method, you can set a breakpoint and step more slowly through the code to determine what is actually not working properly.

Comment: That answered it! I was foolish and wrote the entire program and didn't test it a single time, so i had to do a thorough debug when I had 100 crash sites :( :D :P

Comment: @yash101 - I would start again and implement each function as needed copying that bit of code from the original - then you have one crash site at a time

Comment: I got the program to work. I spent an hour and completely rewrite the code, this time using the power of common sense. Now, my program works, better than I would have expected. The code will be available on GitHub, next year (after this FRC season) for you all to check out!